# Keeping track of position in searched text when the same word appears more than once

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, data-structures

```
def test():
    
    users_note = """There is a substantial need for child mental health support – 
                    evidence shows that at any given year, 
                    1 in 10 young people will have a diagnosable mental health problem. 
                    Out of these incredibly high numbers, 
                    70% of these young people do not receive adequate mental health support at all, 
                    and of the 30% that do, 
                    only half of them improve. 
                    Though we have evidence-based intervention techniques that work, 
                    we are still relying on outdated technologies and delivery mechanisms. 
                 """
    note_list = users_note.split()
   
    while True:
        for users_try in range(5):
            word_list = input('Enter words you gonna say next: ').split()
            for word in word_list:
                if word not in note_list:
                    print('Sorry, try again')
                else:
                    print(note_list[note_list.index(word) + 1])
        else:
            break
```

This function is essentially a teleprompter. When the user inputs a word or multiple words in any order, the function prints the word right after each of the user's input words. However, there's an edge case when an input word occurs multiple times within the pre-made text; the function always prints the word the *first* occurrence. How can this function be modified in order to keep track of the user's input word position within the pre-made text? For example:

*For the first occurrence of `"a"` in the pre-made text:*

```
Enter words you gonna say next: a

substantial
```

*If the user has already passed that point in the text, inputting `"a"` a second time:*

```
Enter words you gonna say next: a

diagnosable
```

*For the first occurrence of `"these"` in the pre-made text:*

```
Enter words you gonna say next: these

incredibly
```

*If the user has already passed that point in the text, inputting `"these"` a second time:*

```
Enter words you gonna say next: these

young
```

In other words, the program should continue moving forward in the text once a word has already been searched for. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Tip: your `break` doesn't do anything. A `for` loop's `else` block is only reached once the loop is finished iterating. Since it's already done, there's no point in also trying to break out of it.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't intend for the user to ever be able to go backwards in the text, an easy solution is to modify `note_list` as you go:

```
if word not in note_list:
    print('Sorry, try again')
else:
    note_list = note_list[note_list.index(word) + 1:]
    print(note_list[0])
```

This makes it impossible to ever "repeat" a particular word, whether the word is unique or not.